# How to redirect python flask werkzeug logs to a log file when using TimedRotatingHandler?

Tags: python, logging

I've created a TimedRotatingHandler for the Flask server. But all the logs generated by the werkzeug are still thrown on the console.

How can I redirect these logs to the log file(test.log) with the log rotating functionality.

Code snippet:

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# add a file handler
fh = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler("test.log",when='M',interval=1,backupCount=0)
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create a formatter and set the formatter for the handler.
frmt = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(frmt)
# add the Handler to the logger
log.addHandler(fh)
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

The below logs are still thrown on the console.

```
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
* Restarting with stat
192.168.1.6 - - [25/Jun/2015 07:11:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.6 - - [25/Jun/2015 07:11:13] "GET /static/js/jquery-1.11.2/jquery-1.11.2.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
192.168.1.6 - - [25/Jun/2015 07:11:13] "GET /static/js/main/main.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
192.168.1.6 - - [25/Jun/2015 07:11:13] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Adding the log file handler to the werkzeug logger is too not solving the problem

```
logging.getLogger('werkzeug').addHandler(fh);
```

Answer (score 3):

To change werkzeung logging you need to override `logging.root.handler` like:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

handler = RotatingFileHandler('log.log', maxBytes=10000, backupCount=1)
handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

logging.root.handlers = [handler]
```

See [here](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/_internal.py#L76) for details.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like werkzeug sends it messages to the root logger rather than a named logger.

If you try this it should start logging to your file
`logging.getLogger().addHandler(fh)`

If you want it to stop logging to the console then you'll have to remove the stream handler from the root logger. You can see the handlers for the root logger by using

`>>> print logging.getLogger().handlers
[<logging.StreamHandler object at 0x.....>, logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler object at 0x.....>]`

Answer (score 1):

In order to direct the flask server/app log to a file handler and also werkzeug to same file handler, you may want to do something like the following.

```
handler = RotatingFileHandler('test.log', maxBytes=1000000, backupCount=5)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
app.logger.addHandler(handler)
log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.addHandler(handler)
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Comment: This one works for me. Using the same handler for werkzeug indeed allows to redirect the internal logs (with client IPs) to the log.

Answer (score 1):

The `addHandler` will not solve this problem. A logger can have many handlers.

```
from logging.config import dictConfig

dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'file.handler': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'test.log',
            'maxBytes': 4194304,  # 4 MB
            'backupCount': 10,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'werkzeug': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['file.handler'],
        },
    },
})
```

By the way, this is not a problem at all. In a development environment, logs in console is convenient. In a production mode, applications will not run in a console.

Comment: This is the only solution that can work without having access to Flask.app and before starting. Requires a few tweeks by adding a formatter.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the main issue, which was that `app.run(debug=True)` should be removed and be replaced by `app.run()`, because flask werkzeug uses the same method to show the beautified error on the webpage.